# Flickr's "getTopPlacesList" API returns "no data"

Tags: flickr, cs193p

Taking the Fall, 2013 - Winter, 2014 CS 193p class via iTunes U.

I have a valid API key. Even Flickr's "API Explorer" is returning "no data".

Link to Flickr's API Explorer for Top Places List:
http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.places.getTopPlacesList.html

I'm using valid "place_type_ids": 22, 7, 8, 12, 29

The API doesn't throw an error. It returns normally, just without any data: 
"places": { "total" : 0, ...

Have no idea what I'm doing wrong since the API Explorer is not even returning any data.

Thanks in advance to anyone kind enough to offer any help.

~ Lee

Good news - Just tried it (3/20 @ 9:45 PM CDT) and it worked! –  Lee Trent 20 mins ago

Try this link: flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.places.getTopPlacesList –  Lee Trent

Comment: Looks like you’re not the only one, http://www.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/72157642329514773/, http://www.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/72157642468804825/ – so a bug on Flickr’s end maybe.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply!

Comment: Having very same problem right now, taking same course on iTunes U :)))

Comment: @Serzhas, I presume that you're trying to complete Assignment 5 like me. Any ideas regarding a "workaround" to this Flickr "Top Places" API problem so we can complete this assignment? - Lee

Comment: No, unfortunately... I'm currently at lecture 11, and trying to recreate Shutterbug application by myself. Just decided to use Top Places instead of latest photos. Didn't knew this will be at Assignment 5 :) Hope Flickr will take care of problem for us to be able continue with assignment...

Comment: Good news - Just tried it (3/20 @ 9:45 PM CDT) and it worked!

Comment: Try this link: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.places.getTopPlacesList

Answer (score 0):

It's working already. Seems like was some troubles at Flickr itself.

Comment: Lee, could you please contact me at serzhas<at>gmail<dot>com. I'd like to discuss some issues I'm having with Shutterbug (assignment 5 of CS183P). Thanks a lot!